# PRISM/Unity IDisposable

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, unity-container

I have some modules that need to do some tidy up work when they are closing, however it would appear that PRISM/Unity does not respect the IDisposable interface. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this working?

Comment: Did my answer help you at all mate?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue, and solved it like this:

First I created a custom Event to allow me to signal my modules that the container is closing:

```
public class ApplicationExitEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<string> { }
```

Then in my bootstrapper I implement IDisposable and fire the event in my Dispose() method:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var eventAggregator = Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        if (eventAggregator != null)
        {
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<ApplicationExitEvent>().Publish("");
        }
    }
```

Then in my module's Initialize() method I subscribe to this event:

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<ApplicationExitEvent>().Subscribe((o) => Dispose(), true);
```

And put whatever cleanup code I need in my module's Dispose method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your modules are not disposed because they are registered as singleton (shared) components in the container.

`Dispose()` your container manually on `Application.Exit`, and all your disposable modules (and other resolved shared disposable components from this container) should have their `IDisposable.Dispose()` method called.